# Не удается вернуть результат сложения строк

Tags: c++, ооп

Результат метода успешно записывается в переменную, если верить отладчику, но при возвращении переменной данные теряются и возвращается случайный набор символов.

```
    MyString& operator + (const MyString& other)
    {
        MyString result;
        result.str = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(other.str) + 1];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
            result.str[i] = this->str[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(other.str); i++)
            result.str[i+strlen(this->str)] = other.str[i];

        result.str[strlen(str) + strlen(other.str)] = '\0';
        return result;
```

Уточняю код класса:

```
class MyString
{
public:
    MyString()
    {
    str = nullptr;
    size = 0;
    }

    MyString(const char* str)
    {
        size_t size = strlen(str);
        this->str = new char[size+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = str[i];
        }
        this->str[size] = '\0';
    }

    ~MyString()
    {
        delete[] this->str;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << str;
    }

    MyString(const MyString& other)
    {
        size_t size = strlen(other.str);
        this->str = new char[size + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }

        this->str[size] = '\0';
    };

    MyString& operator = (const MyString& other)
    {
        if (this->str != nullptr)
            delete[] str;

        size_t  size = strlen(other.str);
        this->str = new char[size + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        }
        this->str[size] = '\0';

        return *this;
    };

    MyString operator + (const MyString& other)
    {
        MyString result;
        result.str = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(other.str) + 1];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
            result.str[i] = this->str[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(other.str); i++)
            result.str[i+strlen(this->str)] = other.str[i];

        result.str[strlen(str) + strlen(other.str)] = '\0';
        return result;
    }

private:
    char* str;
    size_t size{};
};
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А точно возвращается ссылка (`MyString&`) ? Может надо `return *result;` ? Или просто `MyString` без `&`.

Comment: А что такое класс `MyString` ? Если он ведет себя как `std::string` то вы возвращаете ссылку на локальный объект, который удаляется при выходе из функции. Как написал JohnDoe - верните не ссылку, а просто объект `MyString operator+()`.

Comment: В "достаточно современном" C++ инициализация членов класса возможна "прямо"  в объявлении членов, т.е. сразу пишем `char* str = nullptr; size_t size = 0;`, а в конструкторе уже ничего не нужно писать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя возвращать из функций ссылки и указатели на временные объекты. При выходе из функции эти объекты удаляются и ссылка/указатель становятся невалидными.

```
//MyString& operator + ()  // неправильно
//MyString* operator + ()  // неправильно
MyString operator + ()   // правильно
{
    MyString result; // локальная переменная с временем жизни внутри функции
    ....
    return result;
}  // при выходе из функции result уничтожается
```

Ещё хотелось бы увидеть код самого класса `MyString`.
Потому что вы выделяете память (ресурс) вне класса. Т.е. работа с памятью не инкапсулирована и скорее всего у вас утечка. Вы не поддерживаете идиому [RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) в своем коде.

```
MyString result;
result.str = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(other.str) + 1]; // выделение памяти вручную вне класса
// А освобождение памяти вы сделали?
```

Сразу бросается в глаза - вы не следуете принципу [DRY - Не повторяйся](https://habr.com/ru/company/itelma/blog/546372/).  У вас выделение памяти происходит во многих местах. Для избежания ошибок сделайте служебную функцию и выделяйте/перевыделяйте память в ней, например что-то типа `allocate()`. И её уже вызывайте в остальных методах.
Ещё одна типичная ошибка при работе с ресурсами - вы не сохраняете валидность объекта до конца операции. Всегда нужно учитывать, что при работе с ресурсами может произойти ошибка. В данном случае - ОС не смогла выделить память. В этом случае, объект который был должен сохраниться либо, перейти в другое, но тоже валидное состояние. Т.е. изначальная строка должна остаться как была, либо например стать пустой строкой.

```
MyString& operator = (const MyString& other)
{
    if (this->str != nullptr)
        delete[] str;        // освободили память
    this->str = new char[size + 1];  // а вот здесь произошла системная ошибка и память не выделилась
// в деструкторе вы попытаетесь повторно вызвать delete[] str;

// -------------------
// сохранить исходную строку:
{
    char* tmpstr = new char[size + 1];
    if(!tmpstr)
        throw MemoryError(); // если память не выделилась - как-то прореагировать
    
    if (this->str != nullptr)
        delete[] str;        // освободили память
    str = tmpstr;

// -------------------
// строка становится пустой, но это тоже валидное состояние:
MyString& operator = (const MyString& other)
{
    if (this->str != nullptr)
        delete[] str;        // освободили память
    str = nullptr; 
    size = 0;
    this->str = new char[size + 1];
    if(!tmp.str)
        throw MemoryError(); // если память не выделилась - как-то прореагировать
```

И вот эту всю логику лучше сделать в одном месте - в отдельной функции, чтобы в случае внесения изменений не искать по всему листингу все места, где вы выделяли память.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в вопросе добавил исходный код для всего класса.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. В принципе разработчики за вас это уже решили - используйте `std::unique_ptr<>` и фабричную функцию `make_unique()` вместо сырого указателя `char* str`.

Comment: А разве `new` в общем случае при невозможности выделить память не бросит `std::bad_alloc`?